# Что предпочтительнее конструктор или синтаксис инициализации объекта?

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, инициализация

Собственно C# позволяет объявлять объекты при помощи конструктора и инициализации объекта.

К примеру имеется вот такой класс с множеством свойств:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string ThirdName { get; set; }
        public string Сareer { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public Person(int id) => Id = id;
    }
```

Желательно ли в таких случаях создавать полный конструктор (То есть со всеми свойствами класса) или использовать инициализацию объекта:

```
Person person = new Person(0)
{
    FirstName = "Ололоха",
    SecondName = "Ололохин",
    ThirdName = "Ололохович",
    Company = new Company(),
    Career = "Microprof",
    Phone = "8-800-55-35-55"
};
```

Ясное дело, что для get only свойства в любом случае нужен конструктор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Когда нужно использовать конструктор?**

Если в классе имеются критически важные поля, без инициализации которых экземпляр класса просто не может существовать.

Например, у нас есть класс `TelegramApi`, который позволяет отправлять себе уведомления в телеграмe. Для авторизации при отправке мы используем специальный токен. Т.е.

```
public class TelegramApi
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public void SendNotification(string msg) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Если мы дадим среднему юзеру, нашу библиотеку, то он обязательно напишет вот так:

```
var tg = new TelegramApi();
tg.SendNotification("Hello!");
```

и скажет, что все фигня и ничего не работает. Именно для этого мы добавляем в наш класс один единственный конструктор `TelegramApi(string token)` и делаем невозможным допустить такую ошибку.

**Когда нужно использовать инициализаторы?**

Во всех остальных случаях. Инициализаторы значительно увеличивают скорость написания кода и делают его намного более читабельным. А это крайне важный момент.

Comment: `Инициализаторы значительно увеличивают скорость написания кода` это каким образом?

Comment: @tym32167 а таким, что не нужно тратить время на описание конструктора и массы его перегрузок, а также не нужно все эти конструкторы править при добавлении\удалении полей в классе.

Comment: Это весьма спорное утверждение. Замена параметра конструктора на свойство в инициализаторе - это, во первых, больше текста писать, а во вторых - при удалении свойства также надо править все инициализаторы. Хотя это обычно все можно рефакторингами сделать, что занимает абсолютно одинаковое время.

Comment: @tym32167 не все люди находят определенные вещи очевидными - такое бывает. В любом случае, доказывать вам что-то у меня желания нет.

Comment: Да это без проблем, пусть читатели комментов для себя решают где истина :)

Comment: Ну в плане читабельности инициализатор получше будет точно, особенно если у класса много свойств.

Comment: @TermalAlloy, да ладно, параметры метода/конструктора тоже можно именовать: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Comment: @Андрей NOP В том то и дело что в таком случае нужно именовать, а в инициализаторе всё есть сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор класса по сути является выражением минимальных для класса требований. То есть все обязательные к заполнению свойства, то есть все, что обязательно необходимо для создания экземпляра класса должно быть передано в конструктор.

Иногда бывает, что в разных ситуациях может быть разный набор минимальных требований класса. В таких случаях пользуются перегрузками конструктора.

Также бывает, когда специфика типа предполагает использование конструктора. Например, неизменяемые типы (когда любая операция над типом создает новый экземпляр) предполагают, что все данные, которыми обладает тип, переданы через конструктор.

Также вы можете столкнуться с использованием конструктора при работе с инверсией зависимости. Вообще, инверсия зависимости может работать и с полями\методами, но я например в своей работе в 99% случаях использую только конструктор. По сути, этот принцип и формализует требования для конструктора класса - что все объекты, необходимые для создания экземпляра, должны быть предоставлены через конструктор - это, по сути, и есть назначение всех DI фреймворков.

Подводя итог, можно сказать, что в конструктор надо передавать обязательные поля. Но обязательные для заполнения поля могут быть у сервисов, или, например, у моделей. У POCO объектов (которые, например, используют для сериализации\десериализации или на которые мапят сущности из БД), имхо, полей обязательных нет, так как они представляют собой только данные, а не логику, потому я обычно оставляю их конструктор пустым.