# Для чего служат Конструкторы в c#

Tags: c#

Для чего именно служат конструкторы в C#
Зачем нужно их создавать?
Дайте наглядный пример, пожалуйста.
Возможно вопрос глупый, но я не понимаю =)

Comment: Как вам удобней класс инициализировать, так: `new MyClass() { MyValye = 10 }` или так: `new MyClass(10)`? Это один из способов использования конструкторов - передача данных. Ну а вообще, я вам очень сильно советую начать писать что то самому/самой и у вас моментально отпадут все эти базовые вопросы.

Comment: [Что предпочтительнее конструктор или синтаксис инициализации объекта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850856/179763)

Comment: [Наследование и конструкторы базовых классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/961800/179763)

Comment: Внутри конструктора можно скрыть детали инициализации объекта. К примеру у вас объект может не просто инициализироватся всегда одинаково, а например его инициализация может зависеть от каких то флагов, которые вы можете внутрь конструктора передавать. Таким образом вы скрываете детали инициализации внутрь конструктора подальше от основной высокоуровневой логики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструкторы уже своим названием намекают на свою суть. Нужны они для инициализации объекта. Через них можно передавать какие-то параметры для инициализации:

```
class A
{
    private int T;

    public A()
    {
        T = 1;
    }

    public A(int t)
    {
        T = t;
    }

    public int Calc(int x) => x * t;
}
```

В зависимости от выбранного конструктора (передаем параметр или нет, и какой) - меняется поведение объекта. И теперь мы с помощью конструктора **гарантируем**, что данное поле будет заполнено значением.

Еще он хорошо подходит для инъекций зависимостей. Например так можно реализовать паттерн **Стратегия**:

```
class A
{
    private IStrategy _strategy;

    public A()
    {
        // Если берем конструктор без параметров - то создастся стратегия 
        // по-умолчанию
        _strategy = new DefaultStrategy();
    }

    public A(IStrategy strategy)
    {
        //Если в конструктор передать стратегию - то используется она
        _strategy = t;
    }

    public int Calc(int x) => strategy.Perform(x);
}
```

В классе стратегии может скрываться сколь угодно сложная логика, и в зависимости от стратегии может быть очень разный результат выполнения - возможности огромные.

Так же в конструкторе происходят инициализации разных полей класса которые того требуют:

```
class A
{
    public readonly List<int> FooList;

    public A()
    {
        FooList = new List<int>;
    }
}
```

И вот вам уже не приходится думать и проверять - создали ли вы список или нет, все будет **гарантировано** происходить автоматом при создании объекта.

На деле все подходы сочетаются в разных комбинациях. Примерно тем же занимаются порождающие паттерны типа Абстрактных фабрик и Фабричных методов, но там свою нюансы, и фабрики не исключают использования конструкторов, скорее они друг-друга дополняют. Таким образом конструктор заключает в себе некие рутинные мероприятия которые обязаны выполняться всегда при создании объекта. Это позволяет не повторяться, и держать все в одном месте, инкапсулировать внутри класса.